# How use database for Titanium Desktop Application

Tags: database, titanium, desktop-application

I try to create desktop application using SQLite. I use SQLite to create “test.db” database file with table name “test1”, having “id” and “name” field. I try following code for fetching data from database:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = Titanium.Database.openFile('test.db');
var rows = db.execute( "select * from test1");
alert('result set is: ' + rows.fieldByName('id') + ' : ' + rows.fieldByName('name'));
</script>
```

But this code is not work. Please tell me another way to work with SQLite.

Thanks

Comment: did you try alert(rows)?

Comment: Your db is not opening correctly, try Titanium.Database.install and then alert your db, and see what it shows. http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.2/Titanium.Database.install-method.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 var db = Titanium.Database.openFile(db_path);
        result=db.execute("SELECT * FROM images WHERE ev='"+ev_id+"'AND path='"+Titanium.App.getHome()+"/Resources/"+filename+"'");
        if(result.rowCount())
        {
            width_ratio=w/result.fieldByName("width");
        height_ratio=h/result.fieldByName("height");
}
```